# Print x instead of numbers

Tags: objective-c

I have this code where it will plus or minus 1 to the number when the buttons are clicked.
how can i change it, so it will write example xxxx instead of 4?

i've tried with a while loop but can't seem to get it to work.

```
-(void)Changefouls:(id)sender{
    if (e == 5) {
        e = 5;

        self.homefouls.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", e];
    } else {
        e = e + 1;
        self.homefouls.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", e];

    }


}
-(void)Changefouls2:(id)sender {
    if (e < 1) {
    e = 0;
    self.homefouls.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", e];

   } else {
   e = e - 1;
    self.homefouls.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", e];

   }
}
```

Comment: OK, so `e` is an instance variable and `Changedfouls:` is called for the *plus* button and `Changefouls2:` is pressed for the *minus* button?

Comment: Not clear on the `x`s. Always print 4 `x`s? Or replace each digit in the number with an `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK firstly make your life easier and use names that mean something.

Change `e` to `_foulCount` or `_numberOfFouls` or something else (I have assumed you have declared it in the `@interface` as an instance variable or property).

Next change the action methods to `foulsPlusPressed:` and `foulsMinusPressed:`.

Then:

```
-(void)foulsPlusPressed:(id)sender {
    if (_foulCount == 5)
        return;    // Nothing more to do
    _foulCount++;

    [self _updateFoulsText];    // private method
}

-(void)foulsMinusPressed:(id)sender {
    if (_foulCount == 0)
        return;    // Nothing more to do
    _foulCount--;

    [self _updateFoulsText];    // private method
}

// Private method
- (void)_updateFoulsText {
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _foulCount; i++)
        [str appendString:@"x"];
    self.homefouls.text = str;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to declare the private method.

Answer (score 0):

Here a nice alternative solution without looping using the stringByPaddingToLength method in NSString class. This methods returns a new string formed from the receiver by either removing characters from the end, or by appending as many occurrences as necessary of a given pad string.

Code Example:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // basic UI for demo
    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                               25,
                                                               CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),
                                                               25)];
    _textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    _textField.placeholder = @"text will be replaced with x's";
    [self.view addSubview:_textField];

    UIButton *btnPlus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnPlus.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), 100, 25, 25);
    [btnPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(setPlus) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnPlus setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btnPlus];

    UIButton *btnMinus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnMinus.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), 130, 25, 25);
    [btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(setMinus) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnMinus setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btnMinus];
}

- (void)setPlus {
    /*
    takes the current length for textField and adds one at the beginning 
    */
    _textField.text = [_textField.text stringByPaddingToLength:_textField.text.length + 1
                                                    withString:@"x"
                                               startingAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"adding: %lu", _textField.text.length);
}

- (void)setMinus {
    if (_textField.text.length > 0) { // checks if there anything to remove, avoids out of memory crash
        _textField.text = [_textField.text stringByPaddingToLength:_textField.text.length - 1
                                                        withString:@"x"
                                                   startingAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"removing: %lu", _textField.text.length);
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i< YOURNUMBER; i++)
{
    [str appendString:@"x"];
}
NSLog(@"%@ str");
```

This use for loop and it will enumerate as many times as YOURNUMBER value and it will add x string to the str object. The NSLog line just print the result to the console. You probably want to replace it with:

```
self.homefouls.text = str;
```

Comment: maybe you should explain him your solution and don't just paste in the code. I think it is clear that OP needs some guidance because he is a beginner.

Comment: @dehlen I've added explanation but I think this code is self explanatory. It's simple for loop every programmer should know.